# how do I go about choosing rows in a spreadsheet with user input value in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with columns like stock name, country, industry, and stock price. I want to have the user provide the name of the country and VBA selects rows corresponding with that country. The end result should be a range of rows corresponding that country only. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Why not have your data as a table or pivottable and just filter?

Comment: Sounds like a userform would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SelectCountry = InputBox("Type country name")   'Inputbox to get contry name

If SelectCountry <> "" Then     'filter is user type country name
    'My data is insert Table named Table1, change it according to your table name
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table1").AutoFilter Field:=2         'Table must be clear before filter, 2 refer country column no
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=SelectCountry   'Filter
End If
```